# How can we convert .proto file and JSON descriptors?

Tags: javascript, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js, bigquery-udf

I'd like to convert from .proto file to JSON descriptors.

.proto file is like as this:
https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/blob/master/google/protobuf/type.proto

JSON descriptors is like as this:
https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/blob/master/google/protobuf/type.json

The reason why　I'd like to use protobuf on bigquery udf with using bq-udf-protobuf.
https://github.com/salrashid123/bq-udf-protobuf
So, I think I need to prepare sentences like as JSON descriptors for my SQL.

Answer (score 4):

Robocco, you can convert your proto file definition into protobufjs.Root and then use method toJSON() to get JSON descriptor.

Here is a related [example](https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/tree/master/ext/descriptor) from documentation.

```
const protobufjs = require("protobufjs")

const root = protobufjs.loadSync('test.proto');
// Alternative way without loading proto string from file 
// const root = protobufjs.parse('syntax = "proto3"; ...').root;​
console.log(JSON.stringify(root.toJSON(), null, 4));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer might be more helpful to others if you explained how/why it works :)

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).